# Unable to create Flutter Project anywhere in windows

Tags: flutter

I have made many flutter projects, but suddenly I am unable to create a project. I thought it was an issue with VSCode, so, I installed the latest version. Didn't work! Then I tried in Android Studio. It got stuck at 'Creating Flutter Project'. I even tried in CMD. It remains stuck at

```
Running "flutter pub get" in note ...
Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second
```

This is `flutter doctor -v`

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (13 days ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\nithi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.47.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\nithi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I looked into other answers.

Flutter SDK is stored at `C:\flutter`

I feel something is wrong with the SDK itself.

Can someone help me with this issue?

**EDIT**

This is `flutter upgrade`

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 1.17.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8af6b2f038 (13 days ago) • 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
Engine • revision ee76268252
Tools • Dart 2.8.4
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the SDK in case it's corrupted? or doing ```flutter upgrade``` and making sure you're on the stable channel?

Comment: Yes, I initially thought I could do that. But when I run flutter upgrade, it says I'm on the latest stable version. Is there any other way, other than reinstalling the sdk?

Comment: This issue could be related to internet configuration. Can you please try and create a flutter application using hotspot from your mobile data?

Comment: I tried both. Same result. But it really was an internet issue. I rebooted my desktop and router and its working now! But I still don't know what the issue was. Internet worked fine for posting this on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for the lateness in this.

If this is in a Corporate work environment, there may be a 'man in the middle' security scanning app that's preventing the project from being created.

I was using Flutter just fine until my company instituted 'Zscaler'. Since that got implemented, I'd also freeze at that same error message. I had to turn Zscaler off for my Flutter projects to create.